# In SQL Server can I implement the avg function manually? problem passing the name of the column to use

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I want to create a function similar to the avg where I receive the column name as a parameter and query a table to get the values for the specified column.

Maybe this is not possible as I saw that I cannot use exec for the common solution outside functions that is to concatenate the query string and execute it.

```
create function myAvg(@columnName varchar(255))
returns float
as
begin
    declare @queryStr varchar(255) = '(select AVG(cast(' + @columnName + ' as float)) from functionTest)';
    return execute( @queryStr);
end
```

I get this error:

> RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument

Another solution with cursors:

```
create function myAvg (@columnName varchar(255))
returns float
as
begin
    declare @MyCursor as cursor;
    declare @value float;
    declare @total float = 0.0;
    declare @nElems int = 0;

    set @MyCursor = cursor for
                       select @columnName from functionTest;

    open @MyCursor;

    fetch next from @MyCursor into @value;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @total = @total + @value;
        set @nElems = @nElems + 1;

        fetch next from @MyCursor into @value;
    end

    close @MyCursor;
    deallocate @MyCursor;

    return @total /@nElems
end
```

Calling the cursor solution throws this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

I guess functions can't be that versatile with dynamic column parameterization.

Is there an alternative?

Edited: I know I can do this in a stored procedure but then I can't call it from a query.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Why can't `AVG()` do what you want it to? How are you trying to use this function?

Comment: The Avg is an example for demonstration, I wanted to do more complex things.
Looking at the responses I have to go with the CLR functions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use execute in functions. for this purpose is better to use CLR functions. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for the tip.I think I really have to go with CLR.
Will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want to do.

First, you cannot replace an identifier -- such as a column name -- with a parameter.  That is simply not how parameters work.  They only replace constant values.

Second, a function cannot execute dynamic SQL.  You can get around the first problem using dynamic SQL, but that is not allowed in a function.

So, you cannot have a function that takes a column names as an argument and returns the average.

Instead, you can just use a window function in the outer query:

```
select . . . ,
       avg(column_name) over ()
from . . .;
```

Note:  There actually is a way using a very complicated method of re-invoking a query in SQL Server, but it is not worth it.

Comment: Thank you for the window function tip, for my demo problem it would solve the problem. 
But I was trying to see how I could do more complex functions and I think I have to go with CLR function.

Comment: @AfonsoR. . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Not quite, I asked: In SQL Server can I implement the avg function manually? And the other answer gave a way to do what I wanted.
I appreciate your answer, but I can only accept one.